# Rails 3.0 - is there a built-in search functionality in any of ActiveRecord classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, ruby-on-rails-3, geolocation

I'm kind of new to rails - I'm currently learning by developing a web-app, similar to the [Agile Rails book](http://pragprog.com/titles/rails3/agile-web-development-with-rails-third-edition) (with iteration and all).

Knowing rails, I know there's a great way to search in the database. So my question simply is: what is the good way to do so? - the rails way.

Search criteria are classics (keywords in sentences, strings, ...) AND a "near" search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We're using [Sphinx](http://github.com/freelancing-god/thinking-sphinx) here. It's a fulltext search engine, if you're looking for that.

Comment: I'll look into that for search on text. Regarding geo-search, I've found this http://github.com/andre/geokit-rails.